# RegEx is Too Greedy

Tags: c#, regex, greedy, regex-greedy

I have requirement to validate a range. 
The input is in the following format:

```
string example1 = "anydate between 20100101 ~~ 20100101";
string example2 = "anydate between 20100101 and 20100101";
string example3 = "docid between 1 ~~ 2";
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
\b(\w)*(?<operator>Between|contains)\b(?<prefix>.*).*?(?<OP>~~|and)[  ]?\b(?.*)\b
```

When user inputs `"anydate between 20100101 ~~ 20100101 and test1"` it is failing and it captures till `test1`.

How to make my regex less greedy and only caputure till `20100101`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
anydate\b(?<op>(between|contains))\b(?<first>[0-9]*)\b(?<op2>(~~|and))\b(?<second>[0-9]*)
```

*edit* Guessing at whats needed but:

```
(?<func>\w+)\b(?<op>(between|contains))\b(?<first>\w+)\b(?<op2>(~~|and))\b(?<second>\w+)
```

Comment: Thanks but search criteria could be date or any other field. I have taken date as example.

Comment: Then what exactly is the specification?